# How to add a string to the end a cell in a xlsx file if it is over a certain number of characters in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have my java code below from what I've done so far to get the table to show up in the eclipse console.
I cannot find a solution anywhere on how to add a string to the end of the cell if it is over a certain number of characters.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class excelreader {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("book1.xlsx"));

XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

FormulaEvaluator formEvaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

for(Row row : sheet){

    for(Cell cell : row){
        switch(formEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType())
        {

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                System.out.print(cell.getDateCellValue()+"\t");
            } else {
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+"\t\t\t");
            }
            break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: 
            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+ "\t\t\t");  
            break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            System.out.print(cell.getErrorCellValue()+"\t\t\t");
            break;

        }

    }


    System.out.println();
}
}
}
```

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html

Comment: I've looked through that page a couple times along with everything i can find that pops up on google and cant find a quick answer

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue(java.lang.String)   I don't see anything in your code where you're testing for length though?

Comment: Yea I deleted it out because nothing I was trying was working. I was trying to do a if statement using the cell reference but inside of the SWITCH instead of printing it before the switch case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by modifying your code like this:

```
...
String strCellValue;
DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        switch (formEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType()) {

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            strCellValue = df.formatCellValue(cell);
            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                if (strCellValue.length() > 5) {
                    System.out.print(df.formatCellValue(cell) + "...");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(df.formatCellValue(cell));
                }
                System.out.print("|");
            } else {
                if (strCellValue.length() > 5) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "...");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                }
                System.out.print("|");
            }
            break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            strCellValue = df.formatCellValue(cell);
            if (strCellValue.length() > 5) {
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "...");
            } else {
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
            System.out.print("|");
            break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            strCellValue = df.formatCellValue(cell);
            if (strCellValue.length() > 5) {
                System.out.print(cell.getErrorCellValue() + "...");
            } else {
                System.out.print(cell.getErrorCellValue());
            }
            System.out.print("|");
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
}
...
```

- I am adding "**`...`**" if the length of cell value is greater than 5.
- Note that for date cell value part, I have changed **`cell.getDateCellValue()`** to **`df.formatCellValue(cell)`** because if you'll keep your original it will print **`6/23/2016`** your date as **`Thu Jun 23 00:00:00 EDT 2016`**.

Also in my suggestion, you really don't need to use **`Case`** statement. You can simply use magic of [**DataFormatter**](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) instead, like this:

```
...
String strCellValue;
DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        strCellValue = df.formatCellValue(cell);
        if (strCellValue.length() > 5) {
            System.out.print(df.formatCellValue(cell) + "...");
        } else {
            System.out.print(df.formatCellValue(cell));
        }
        System.out.print("|");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I was stuck on it for hours last night trying to figure out how to get it to read the number of characters using length of the cell but couldn't get the right if statement usng cellvalue.length to work.                       thanks again though

Comment: Glad to help. If you can [**accept**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer other will know that you get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If i understood correctly your aim, but this is how I interpreted it.

"I want to append data to a cell value if the length of the cell value is greater than a defined value"

So a partial solution would be to simply do a length() > nnn (where nnn is the integer length you're checking) check for cells with Cell.CELL_TYPE_TRING such as:

```
String stringCellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
if (stringCellValue != null) {
    if(stringCellValue.length() > nnn) {
        // Do your append to cell value here
    }
}
```

You could also potentially do something similar for the other cell types by casting the retrieved cell value to an appropriate object

e.g. cast cell.getNumericCellValue() to a java.lang.Double and call toString() on that Double.

Date cell types will be more difficult to cast and stringify to determine an appropriate string representation as you would need a date format to apply to the date.

Comment: yea so for example i want to add the string "..." to any cell that has over 50 characters in it